# ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'the first non-integer result from my table' when using an update stmt

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a select statement of a string column to set out alphanumeric values free of pure integars using the following statement:
select `some_col_1` from `some_table` where `some_col_1` = 'some value' and length(cast(`some_col_1` as unsigned)) != length(`some_col_1`)

Whereas, I am trying to update some other column based on that condition using update statement,

My problem is, whenever I attempt to run the select statement, it is being successfully executed, meanwhile when I essentially use an update statement only gives some kind of unexpected error which is: ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'the first non-integer result from my table'.

I just can't figure out why it is doing this. Is there any experts who can see anything odd in my update statement? I am using mysql server version 8.0 and my update stmt precisely goes as follows:

update `some_table` set `some_col_2` = true where `some_col_1` = 'some value' and length(cast(`some_col_1` as unsigned)) != length(`some_col_1`)

Your support with this would be very highly appreciated,
Thank you in advance,

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  what column do you mean by `the first non-integer result from my table`?

Comment: can you explain what you expect your length cast != length to accomplish?

Comment: select version() gives 8.0.23

Comment: I mean the first non-integer result (or row) from a normal select query from the table

Comment: I use length(cast(col as unsigned)) != length(col) condition in order to apply the update another secondary column based on weather the primary column holds a pure numeric value or an alpha-numeric value

Comment: huh.  that doesn't work if it only has a single character.

Comment: What this primarily does is that it says if the column has an alpha numeric value or a numeric value by checking the length of the integer in a cell. For example length(cast 123456  as unsigned) shall be equal to 6, whereas length(cast (123abc as unsigned)) shall be equal to 3.

Comment: it does work for a select statement, it is only when i replace select by update the error happens!

Comment: but `length(cast('a' as unsigned))` is 1, so equals `length('a')`

Comment: agreed, and so is length(cast('abc' as unsigned)) is also 1. I have no cells with length of 1 in the table so I thought it is okay if I use the condition the same way I have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are running into is mysql's sloppy way of implementing STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode, which is intended to give an error when trying to set a value to something that has to be modified to meet the column's specification.

mysql chose to implement this by making things like cast or date parsing just give errors, instead of warnings, when done in a data modification statement, even when those expressions weren't what was actually attempted to be stored.

You can either disable STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode for the duration of your update:

```
set session sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');
update ...
```

or use an alternate way of detecting your case that doesn't involve something that triggers a warning, or under STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, an error.  For instance:

```
update some_table set some_col_2=true where some_col_1 not regexp '^([1-9][0-9]*|0)$';
```